# Unable to print documents in WCF service using amyuni converter

Tags: .net, windows, wcf, iis, printing

We have an application service hosted in IIS which is using Amyuni PDF Converter 6.0 to print the report in PDF file. The application was working fine with Amyuni PDF Converter 5.5.

This issue is seen in **Windows Server Operating System & When the service is hosted on IIS**. Whereas in Windows 10 OS the application seems to be working fine.

When trying to print using a console application either on Windows Server or Windows 10 OS, we are able to print the document.

We ensured that both console applications and services were run under the same user/Identity.

Any advice on this issue?

Comment: You should contact with Amyuni. Maybe they change something between versions.

Comment: We could not figure out the issue with Amyuni 6, We continued to work with Amyuni 5.5 instead.